# Creating repeatable BSOD scenarios (for teaching)?

Tags: windows, bsod

This could probably just as easily go in stackoverflow or a few other places, but I expect I will get the best answers here since there are always lots of blue screen issues waiting to be resolved.

I'm interested in any blue screen scenarios the experts here have come across that are easily repeatable and can either be remotely triggered or occur 0-15 minutes after bootup (with driver verifier enabled if necessary). The more devious, the better documented, and the fewer 3rd party apps required to create the scenarios, the better. Any programs required to create the crash scenarios must be open source, Microsoft-made or free. I am open to using any Windows client or Server OS from the Vista/2008 kernel and newer. The cause of each scenario needs to be able to be reproduced within a virtual machine (vendor-neutral hypervisor is a plus) and must have a definitive fix.

My ultimate goal is to teach IT professionals practical OS troubleshooting and I'm trying to come up with lab ideas for the students to troubleshoot. As such, this needs to be **real world** examples. I want my students to have to debug them with windbg, disable services, and google in order to solve them.

Comment: The first step is test hardware health at Windows BSOD and Linux kernel panic.

Comment: I'm not sure you read through the whole question. I'm not trying to solve a BSOD. I'm trying to create real world examples of them for students to troubleshoot in a lab environment. I've modified my question to be more clear about that.

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy He's asking for Windows BSOD, not Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [NotMyFault](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/notmyfault) which can create several different bugcheck crashes:

> Notmyfault is a tool that you can use to crash, hang, and cause kernel
>   memory leaks on your Windows system. It’s useful for learning how to
>   identify and diagnose device driver and hardware problems, and you can
>   also use it to generate blue screen dump files on misbehaving systems.

[image]

Comment: I actually found this myself too and originally discounted it because I couldn't get specific crashes, but this is by far the best answer I've been able to find. I will close this out and use this as my answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

From [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/forcing-a-system-crash-from-the-keyboard):

> With USB keyboards, you must enable the keyboard-initiated crash in
>   the registry. In the registry key
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\kbdhid\Parameters,
>   create a value named CrashOnCtrlScroll, and set it equal to a
>   REG_DWORD value of 0x01.
>
> You must restart the system for these settings to take effect.
>
> After this is completed, the keyboard crash can be initiated by using
>   the following hotkey sequence: Hold down the rightmost CTRL key, and
>   press the SCROLL LOCK key twice.

You can also start a forkbomb, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13436408/2320453). This constantly spawns new processes until the machines memory is full and the CPU is hogged at 100%.

Comment: I am already aware of that, but I want specific real world examples. A crash dump generated from that will be generic because the crash code is a dead giveaway. I'll revise my question a bit to make that part of the goal more clear, but I want my students to have to analyze the dumps with windbg and google to find the answers. Thanks though.